# UITapGestureRecognizer initWithTarget:action: method to take arguments?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using `UITapGestureRecognizer` because I'm using a `UIScrollView` that acts as a container for my `UILabel`s. Basically I'm trying to use an action method with arguments so I can e.g. send `myLabel.tag` value to the action method to know what action to take depending on what UILabel has has been triggered by a tap.

One way of doing it is having as many action methods as `UILabel`s but that isn't very "pretty" codewise. What I would like to achieve is just having one action method with switch statements.

Is this possible or will I have to do it like this (sigh):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myLabel1Tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLabel1Tap)];
[myLabel1Tap addGestureRecognizer:myLabel1Tap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *myLabel2Tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLabel2Tap)];
[myLabel1Tap addGestureRecognizer:myLabel2Tap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *myLabelNTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLabelNTap)];
[myLabel1Tap addGestureRecognizer:myLabelNTap];

- (void)myLabel1Tap {
// Perform action
}

- (void)myLabel2Tap {
// Perform action
}

- (void)myLabelNTap {
// Perform action
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a single gesture recognizer to the view that is the superview of your various labels:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myLabelTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myLabelTapHandler:)];
[myLabelParent addGestureRecognizer:myLabelTap];
```

Then when you handle the gesture, determine which label was tapped:

```
-(void)myLabelTapHandler:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIView *tappedView = [gestureRecognizer.view hitTest:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view] withEvent:nil];

    // do something with it
}
```

Comment: haven't you forgotten the semi-column in the selector?

Answer (score 5):

You can use just one `UITapGestureRecognizer` and in your gesture handler (your `myLaberXTap`), which has the syntax:

```
 - (void)handleGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
     ...
 }
```

use `gesture.view` to know which view you are working on.