# iOS UIView push view controller

Tags: ios, uiview, mkmapview, pushviewcontroller, user-interaction

Is it possible to push a view controller when a user selects a UIView? I have a UIView that displays an address and coordinates in it and when the user touches it, I want it to push to my map view controller where it will plot the annotation and so on... Thanks!

Comment: Use a UITapGestureRecognizer to grab the touch then from the gesture recognizer delegate method just push the VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your address and coordinates should be inside a view (like a Label).  If you setup a [tap guesture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on it, then the on tap, you can push the view controller.

For example, if it's a label, here's a relevant SO post showing handling a tap on a label: [iOS using UITapGestureRecognizer with UILabel to swipe to the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924410/ios-using-uitapgesturerecognizer-with-uilabel-to-swipe-to-the-next-page)

In that example, they are scrolling to the next page, in your code, you would push the view controller.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleAddressTap:)]; 
[view.addressLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];  // bind the tap to your label with your address ...

- (void) handleAddressTap: (UIGestureRecognizer *) gesture {
    // push your view controller here
}
```